# Enumerate fields within a WSDL entity

Tags: vb.net, wsdl, enumerate

My issue is that I need to update a WebReference based entity that has about 40 fields in it.  Turns out, if I miss a field, and don't include the existing data, the system will erase what is there.  I can't just update the single field, I have to update all fields.

I'm using VB.NET which is also new for me — I admit it, I'm a VBA coder with a ton of MS Access experience.

The code sample I am working on for the WSDL (there's really only one) show that I must manually enumerate each field by name, line by line, populating a local version of this entity with whatever data from the remote entity, then changing the fields i care about, then republishing back to the the original entity.

I am used to being able to enumerate all the fields in recordsets by index values, and be able to update the entire recordset by name, simply by getting the name from the indexed value (i.e `recordset.fields(10).name`). So I never have to worry about name changes or additional fields, plus my code is cleaner.

But in spite of everything I'm trying to do, I cannot seem to get VB to access any of the entity's information except by explicit name. For instance, `product.referencetitle` works but `product.fields[10].name` just gives an error.
I can't even get it to accept a variable, such as `product(varname)`.

Isn't this basic coding?  Why would I ever hard code fieldnames if I can access them dynamically?  My code would break the next time the WebReference is updated and I have new or deleted fieldnames to work with, right?